# Python throw error open image

Tags: python

```
img_data=open('assets\pblogo.png','rb').read()
img_title=MIMEImage(img_data,'png')
img_title.add_header('Content-Id','<pblogo>')
img_title["Content-Disposition"]="inline"

img_data=open('data\report.jpg','rb').read()
img_report=MIMEImage(img_data,'jpeg')
img_report.add_header('Content-Id','<reportimg>')
img_report["Content-Disposition"]="inline"
```

I am using IDLE on win7, and the first png captured well

as to the second:

```
img_data=open('data\report.jpg','rb').read()
```

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'data\report.jpg'

why can't I open the second pic in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r` is carriage return.

Escape the `\`:

```
'data\\report.jpg'
```

or use raw string:

```
r'data\report.jpg'
```

Comment: thanks~There are same Q&A and I do as you said and still not work~Guess what, the file name is "reprot" not "report"...Anyway thanks LOL